# Homestead "No input file specified" with default settings?

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Like title says, homestead.test default set up shows "no input file specified" - I have read every single thread (I think) regarding to this topic and I just can't figure out why this still occurs

Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

I try to show simple Hello world on the screen. I have `index.php` inside `code` directory on my local machine and in the box.

Only error-ish thing what happened during the installation process is when I run `vagrant provision/homestead provision` it shows this red text:

```
homestead-7: You are running composer as "root", while "/home/vagrant/.composer" is owned by "vagrant"
homestead-7: You are already using composer version 1.6.5 (stable channel).
```

I researched this and found github issue: [#806](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/806) - where svpernova09 stated:

> This is nothing to worry about. This is the result of an upstream
>   change to ensure .composer is owned by the vagrant user.

At this point, I have no idea what I can do to make this work.

Any suggestions?

FYI, I have edited `/etc/hosts` -file and run `provision` after each edit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate directory for your project (e.g. `my_project`), put `index.php` in that directory, and update the `sites` section accordingly.

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/my_project
```

After that change run vagrant with:

```
vagrant up --provision
```